# Run Gitlab CI Runner to build docker in shell execution mode

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have a runner with the following config

```
[[runners]]
  name = "my-runner-02"
  url = "https://ci.gitlab.com/"
  token = TOKEN
  executor = "shell"
  [runners.cache]
```

I try to let it run a simple docker building script via shell execution. I have docker engine installed on the machine. My gitlab-ci.yml file looks as follows:

```
before_script:
  - sudo docker info

build_image:
  script:
    - sudo docker build -t booking-app .
    - sudo docker run -d -p 7771:7771 booking-app
```

I get the following error:

```
Running with gitlab-runner 10.8.0 (079aad9e)
  on my-runner-02 aa596928
Using Shell executor...
No passwd entry for user 'gitlab-working-directory=/home/gitlab-runnerrunner'
ERROR: Job failed: exit status 1
```

So this is a problem with the user gitlab-runner I suppose? I don't get what to do with a passwd entry, the gitlab-working-directory or any user rights. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You are invoking docker with 'sudo docker'.  I am pretty sure it is asking for the password bc of the 'sudo'.

Can you remove all the 'sudo'.  I think they are the problem.

Also

1. change executor from shell to docker
2. Make sure to bind /var/run/docker.sock

Comment: That's a good point but unfortunately it did not change anything. Thanks for the suggestion though.